# Como puedo poner un contenedor con array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un array que viene de una api y busco hacer que cada cuatro elementos estén en un nuevo contenedor padre, algo así:

```
<div>
    {/* four childs*/}
</div>
<div>
    {/* four childs*/}
</div>
<div>
    {/* four childs*/}
</div>
....
```

React utiliza `array.map()` y no se me ocurre nada de como hacer para condicionar dibujar los elementos como necesito pintarlos.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando encontré esta solución que me funcionó muy bien que consiste en dividir el array en varios arrays para luego iterarlos así:

```
const arr = Array.from({ length: 36 }, (v, i) => `${i}a`); // para simular el array de la api
let arrayOfArrays = [];

const SPLIT = 4; // Partir en arreglo de 4
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += SPLIT) {
    let arrSplit = arr.slice(i, i + SPLIT);
    arrayOfArrays .push(arrSplit);
}
console.log("Arreglo de arreglos: ", arrayOfArrays );
```

Para montar los elementos en el DOM habría que recorrer cada uno de los arrays:

```
arrayOfArrays.map((el, i) => 
    <div key={i}>
        el.map((item, key) => <div key={i}>{item}</div>)
    </div>
)
```

Creditos a [parzibyte](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/04/16/javascript-dividir-arreglo-pedazos-arreglos-mas-pequenos/?unapproved=3623&moderation-hash=49d21237df2905a772ce3ed36191912d#comment-3623)

Answer (score 0):

Por si sirve de algo, una forma de solucionarlo sería de la siguiente forma.

de primero utilizamos una variable que tendrá los 4 elementos a mostrar en el `div`, que en este caso son elementos `String`

```
  let elements = '';
```

lo siguiente sería saber cuando son 4 elementos, por lo que usamos el index del recorrido que realiza el `map` para la siguiente formula que nos regresa un residuo

```
(i+1) % 4 === 0
```

Tomando un `array` básico de ejemplo quedaría todo de esta forma

```
const data = [
    'element1',
    'element2',
    'element3',
    'element4',
    'element5',
    'element6',
    'element7',
    'element8',
    'element9',
  ]
  let elements = '';

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((e,i) =>{
        elements += e+' '
        if( (i+1) % 4 === 0){
          const div = <div key={e} >nuevo div {elements}</div>
          elements = '';
          return div;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, probare a ver que tal me va

Comment: @Andersson Recuerda marcar una respuesta como correcta, aun siendo tu propia respuesta, para otros usuarios sepan como solucionar problemas similares